How can I get the Console to display "can’t" instead of "canÕt"?
It's only a small thing I guess, but I'm annoyed to see errors reported in the console for my AppleScripts where the text of the error message contains substitute characters. e.g.
Error Number: -43  Error Message: The operation canÕt be completed.
In the error message "can’t" has been replaced by "canÕt"
I’m not sure if this a failure of AppleScript, the shell or console.app.
I've tried the usual routes of examining console.app (no settings), System Settings (language & regions and keyboard characters seems not to affect console output).
This example demonstrates the problem:
set appName to "textTester"
set targetFolder to "Virtuality:Users:minmin:Documents:" -- an non-existent destination forces the error
try
    tell application "System Events"
        set theResult to name of every file of targetFolder
    end tell
on error errMsg number errNum
    set logEntry to (linefeed & errNum & space & errMsg & linefeed) as text
    tell me to writeToLogFile(logEntry, appName) -- error messagess generated by AppleScript itself create the problem
    tell me to writeToLogFile("Who would've thought I can't log this text properly?", appName) -- demonstrates that writing directly to the log is fine 
end try

on writeToLogFile(logEntry, appName)
    local handlerName
    set handlerName to "writeToLogFile"
    set theDate to do shell script "date '+_%Y_%m_%d'"
    set theDate1st to do shell script "date '+_%Y_%m'" --real date 1st would be "date '+_%m_1_%Y'"
    
    set libPath to path to library folder from user domain as string
    set theFolderPath to (libPath & "Logs:") as string
    set theFilePath to (theFolderPath & appName & ":") as string
    
    set theFileName to (appName & theDate1st & ".log")
    set theFile to (theFilePath & theFileName)
    
    try
        set okToContinue to false
        tell application "Finder"           
            --make sure the folder is there
            if (not (exists folder theFilePath)) then
                make new folder at theFolderPath with properties {name:appName}
            end if
            
            --make sure the logfile is there - or turn it over
            if (not (exists theFile)) then
                set theFile to make new file at theFilePath with properties {name:theFileName, file type:"TEXT", creator type:"ttxt"}
            end if
            
            --open and write logfile entries
            set theFile to theFile as alias
            tell me
                set writetoTheThing to open for access theFile with write permission
                write (logEntry & return) to writetoTheThing starting at eof
                
                close access (writetoTheThing)
            end tell
            set okToContinue to true
        end tell
        
    on error errMsg number errNum
        log errMsg
    end try
    return okToContinue
    
end writeToLogFile

Is there indeed a fix?

How about log command in the UTF-8 terminal.app? Is it the same? Can you post your code that cause this in applescript?

A google search for "canÕt" brings up many similar encoding errors, but no solution found.

Apple internally uses unicode extensively, this should never have happened.

It sounds like you may have"smart punctuation" active by mistake.  Even in your post, the apostrophe in your can't is not the ascii version but U+2019. This can mess up display in console.

@TomGewecke I tried turning off Smart Text in System Preferences/Keyboard/Text but have seen no change in behaviour. All this in macOS Mojave where I am stuck until my target apps become 64-bit

I think it must be a problem in Console app.  No idea how to fix anything there.

@TomGewecke: The problem (I think) is not the Console, but AppleScript, which (perhaps for historical reasons) does not write UTF-8 encoded strings.

The AppleScript command
write (logEntry & return) to writetoTheThing starting at eof

writes the string in Mac OS Roman encoding (or probably the “system encoding” – a remnant from old Mac OS times).
On the other hand, experiments show that the Console application displays UTF-8 encoded text correctly, whereas invalid UTF-8 is apparently interpreted as Windows-1252.
In your case, the "’" in "can’t" is the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK U+2019. Its Mac OS Roman code is 0xD5 and that is written to the file. In the Windows-1252 encoding, 0xD5 is "Õ" which is what you see in the Console app.
The fix (found here on Stack Overflow) is to tell AppleScript to write UTF-8 encoded strings with as «class utf8»:
write (logEntry & return) to writetoTheThing starting at eof as «class utf8»

Now "’" is written as UTF-8 0xE2 0x80 0x99 and displayed correctly in the Console app.

Nice catch! Is there any other places where macOS doesn't use UTF-8 by default?

@hym3242: Ten years ago I noticed that NSLog and some NSString functions expect string arguments in the system encoding. But Swift has much better logging  and string functions now, so nobody will use these anymore. There may be other cases, but right now I am not aware of any.

It's still not clear to me  how the error message winds up containing the curly apostrophy (MacRoman D5) instead of the asci verion (27) in the first place.  Then, to read that D5 as  Õ, you need to be using Win 1252 rather than UTF-8.

@TomGewecke: "can’t" is written as hex 63 61 6E D5 74 0D to the file, that I have verified. D5 74 is not a valid UTF-8 sequence. Perhaps the Console app then guesses the encoding and uses the Windows encoding. – Anyway with the “class utf8” option everything works correctly.

@TomGewecke: Similarly the Euro sign is written as hex DB (MacRoman), and the Console app display that as Û, which is DB in the Windows-1252 encoding.

The 74 is just the "t", so I guess the invalid utf-8 is the D5 on its own.  But to have D5 there instead of 27 must be some kind of bug/error too.

@TomGewecke: As I see it, the failing file operation  in the AppleScript creates an error message "The operation can’t be completed" where "’" is the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2019) and not the APOSTROPHE (U+0027). If you log that to the Terminal then it is correctly displayed. The problem is that the character is converted to Mac OS Roman when writing to a file.

Yes, correct, but whoever created that message in the software should have used the ascii apostrophe character.  I don't know of any others that do not.
